# how to integrate NMI payment gateway with Omnipay?

Tags: php, laravel

Omnipay is a popular payment library in Laravel that provides a unified API for interacting with various payment gateways.  how to integrate the NMI payment gateway using the OmniPay Laravel package in Laravel. Please give some references or steps to follow.

Comment: Check the package description. Package implementation will be there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.